# Proper way to execute raw SQL with Postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

At the moment when I need to execute a complex query that can't be expressed with Arel I do something like this:

```
q = "-- complex stuff here"
sql = ActiveRecord::Base.send(:sanitize_sql_array, [q, x, y, z])
ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute(sql)
```

I don't like calling private method to sanitize user input, is there a better way?